# Custom query: Get all posts that are from a certain category?

Tags: wp-query, wpdb

This is what I have:

```
global $wpdb, $month;

$months = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT *
    FROM $wpdb->posts
    WHERE post_type = 'post' AND post_status = 'publish'
    AND DATE_FORMAT( post_date_gmt, '%Y' ) = $y
    GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT( post_date_gmt, '%Y-%m' )
    ORDER BY post_date_gmt DESC
");
```

The problem is, this returns all posts from that time, but I want only posts that are in category 11.

Is there an easy way to achieve this?

Comment: You don't need to use wpdb. You can use WP_Query to get all posts from a certain category.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's quite easy:

```
$months = $wpdb->get_col("SELECT DATE_FORMAT(post_date_gmt, '%m')
                            FROM $wpdb->posts
                            LEFT JOIN  $wpdb->term_relationships  as t
                            ON ID = t.object_id
                            WHERE post_type = 'post' AND post_status = 'publish' AND t.term_taxonomy_id = 11
                            AND DATE_FORMAT(post_date_gmt, '%Y') = $y
                            GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(post_date_gmt, '%Y-%m')
                            ORDER BY post_date_gmt DESC");
```

term_taxonomy_id is the category. And I join on the object ID

Answer (score 1):

The best way to get all posts from a specific category within WordPress is to use the native class `WP_Query`, and not the `$wpdb` method.

Here is a query example using WP_Query:

```
<?php

    $args = array(
        // Arguments for your query.
    );

    // Custom query.
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );

    // Check that we have query results.
    if ( $query->have_posts() ) {

        // Start looping over the query results.
        while ( $query->have_posts() ) {

            $query->the_post();

            // Contents of the queried post results go here.

        }

    }

    // Restore original post data.
    wp_reset_postdata();

?>
```

In your scenario all we need to do now is specify in the query arguments the category parameter `cat` and your desired category's `ID`, like so:

```
$args = array(
    'cat' => '11',
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish'
);
```

There are [many more parameters and values](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) you can feed to the query's argument.

Hope this helps!

Comment: can you implement the rest of the query as well using `$args` ? because the reason I was using the raw db query was because it would _not_ let me solve exactly what I wanted, using `WP_Query`

Comment: @Toskan What 'exactly' do you want to do, then? You've only mentioned needing to get all posts from a specified category. Maybe you could clarify your additional requirements by editing your original post?

Comment: basically everything that is in the `wpdb` sql query needs to work, I guess otherwise I wouldn't have done it (this is a question from 2015). Post type and status you can get via wp_query I guess. `DATE_FORMAT(post_date_gmt, '%Y') ` is the year like `2017` so all posts in that year, grouped by year + month and ordered by date. I will upvote you because 600 views is a lot and I guess most people want your answer, not my custom query

Answer (score 0):

To show all posts from a category ID 11. Use following loop. It will show all posts from category ID 11.

```
// WP_Query arguments for category Id 11
 $args = array (
     'cat'                    => '11',
 );
```

// The Query
 $query = new WP_Query( $args );
// The Loop
 if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
     while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
         $query->the_post();
         // rest of loop code
     }
 } else {
     // no posts found
 }

// Restore post data loop
 wp_reset_postdata();